# Creating matrix of zeros then writing each row on separate line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to create a matrix of zeros of a certain size. I then need to write each element of this matrix into a file, so that every row is on a separate line with brackets () around it. I also need the output to be in scientific notation, without any commas or square brackets around the data. This is what I have so far:

```
groups = 2

null_array = np.zeros((groups,groups))

for i in range (groups):
    f.write(" (")
    for j in range (groups):
        f.write(null_array(i,j))
    f.write(" )\n")
```

Basically, for groups = 2 I want to end up with this:

```
 (0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 )
 (0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 )
```

The 'groups' variable will change and eventually the input matrix will not be zeros, it will be data read in from a separate file. I am using zeros for now to test the general framework of my script.

At the moment my error message is:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I also cannot work out how to strip the commas and square brackets out of the numpy-generated zeros matrix, and how to make it default to scientific notation.

Comment: Why do you think Python thinks `null_array(i,j)` should be callable?

Comment: `null_array(i,j)` is a function call. `null_array[i,j]` is indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `null_array(i, j])` with `null_array[i, j]`

Indexing is `[]`, while function calls are `()`